# Was ist "was" im Dativ?

Tags: interrogative

Was ist "was" im Dativ für leblose oder abstrakte Gegenstände?
Ist das "wem" oder "was"?

Feierabendbeschäftigung - eine Beschäftigung, der nach Feierabend nachgegangen wird.

Wie stellt man zu dem Satz eine Frage:

> 1. Wem wird nach Feierabend nachgegangen?
> 2. Was wird nach Feierabend nachgegangen?

---

Weitere Sätze zum Fragen:

- Dem kann ich nicht glauben.
- Dem Prozess würde es helfen.
- Dem Patriotismus wurde ein neuer Schwung gegeben.
- Nicht der Angst nachgeben!

Comment: https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/der#Relativpronomen.2C_m.2C_f -> Relativpronomen, weiblich, "der" => Dativ. Also "Wem" wird nachgegangen. — Den Titel der Frage verstehe ich übrigens nicht.

Comment: @Em1 Vielleicht bezieht sich der OP auf die Lücke, die man hier auf [dieser Tabelle](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/was) findet. D. h. es lautet "was, wessen, (Lücke), was"; weil *wem* veilleicht nach dem Dativ von *wer*, und nicht nach dem von *was*, klingt.

Comment: Ohne grammatikalische Argumentation finde ich, hören sich beide Varianten tatsächlich korrekt an :) Da ich "wem" aber auch eher personenbezogen sehe, tendiere ich zu "was", sprich 2.

Comment: Zwei von den drei nachträglich hinzugefügten Sätzen sind vor allem ungrammatisch.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Die ursprüngliche Neutrumform des Fragepronomens im Dativ *was* wird meistens vermieden, vermutlich weil sie mit dem Nominativ und Akkusativ identisch ist. Allenfalls mit einer Präposition, die dann einen eindeutigen Kontext bietet, wird sie manchmal verwendet:

> Von was habt ihr gerade geredet?
>   An was ist sie gestorben?

Das gilt aber als umgangssprachlich. In der Standardsprache würde man für die Kombination aus Präposition und *was* ein Pronominaladverb verwenden:

> Wovon habt ihr gerade geredet?
>   Woran ist sie gestorben?

Auch *wem* wird nicht gern verwendet, weil es Personen vorbehalten ist. Ein Verb wie *nachgehen*, das auch in nicht übertragener Bedeutung üblich ist, ist da nicht hilfreich.

Daher würde man eine andere Formulierung wählen und etwa fragen:

> Welcher Tätigkeit wird nach Feierabend nachgegangen?
>   Was *(Akk.)* betreibt man nach Feierabend?

Comment: danke für die Antwort, aber ich meinte die Verben, die nur mit dem Dativ verwendet werden. Der erste und der zweite Teil von deiner Antwort ist eigentlich überflüssig. Ich suche noch solche Verben und vervollständige die Frage.

Comment: @Deni du könntest vielleicht *geben + (Dat)* nutzen als Beispiel (dafür würde ich auch mich interessieren).

Comment: Es gilt leider nur für Personen und nicht für Gegenstände.

Comment: @c.p.: Wobei es da dasselbe ist wie mit dem Fragepronomen, die Formulierung aus deinem Kommentar klingt seltsam und gilt standardsprachlich nicht als richtig. Man würde es wieder vermeiden und _einer Sache Schwung geben_ oder so etwas sagen.

Comment: @chirlu Danke, fair enough, aber was ich nicht glauben könnte ist, dass *geben* nur Menschen als Dativobjekt erlaubt. (Dies oder vielleicht verstehe ich die Frage nicht und die Diskusion nicht vieles bringt.)

Comment: [Voriger Kommentar bezieht sich auf einen mittlerweile gelöschten Kommentar von @c.p.] Es fällt mir kein Beispiel mit _geben_ ein, abgesehen von _Tieren Futter geben_, _Pflanzen Wasser geben_ u.ä., wo sie eher personenartig auftreten. Bei _nachgeben_ geht es. – Der Punkt ist, daß es zu _etwas_ ebensowenig eine Dativform gibt wie zu _was_. Wenn du nicht eines dieser Wörter verwenden willst, hast du kein Problem: _Sie hat **dem Druck** ein wenig nachgegeben._ _Sie hat **ihm** ein wenig nachgegeben._ Aber nicht: _\*Was hat sie ein wenig nachgegeben?_ _\*Sie hat etwas ein wenig nachgegeben._

Comment: Ok, alles klar.

Answer (score 1):

Bei der Deklination von "was" gibt es eigentlich nur Nominativ und Akkusativ. Und Formen mit Präposition. Statt umgangssprachlich "von was" verwendet man schriftsprachlich "wovon"; das gilt für alle Verbindungen mit Präpositionen.

Bei der Deklination von was fehlen also Formen, es ist eine defektive Deklination.

De.wiktionary hat was wessen -- was. Der Dativ fehlt also ganz. Die Form wessen halte ich für fraglich. In älteren Lehrbüchern findet man sogar "wes", Kurzform von wessen und das Beispiel: wes Geistes Kind jemand ist. Aber das ist eine vereinzelte Anwendung und man kann nicht sagen "wes" sei der Genitiv von was. Ich kenne auch keinen Fall, wo "wessen" Genitiv von was ist. Aber vielleicht gibt es so was doch.

Ich meine, wenn man schon eine Genitivform angibt, dann müßten dafür auch Belegsätze angegeben werden.

https://de.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/was#was_.28Deutsch.29

Zu den im Post gebrachten Sätzen mit Dativ würde man fragen mit "welcher Sache": Nicht der Angst nachgeben. - Welcher Sache/welchem Gefühl sollte man nicht nachgeben.

Comment: Gute Antwort! Zu *wes Geistes Kind* siehe [Lemma *wer* im Grimmschen DWB](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GW17265#XGW17265). Zuerst hieß es in der dt. Bibel noch *wes geists ir seit* (analog gr. & lat.), dann kam Luther mit *welches geistes kinder ir seid* und später diese komische Form *wes geistes kind*.