# Was ist der Genitiv von „was“?

Tags: single-word-request, genitive

Mit „was“ meine ich hier das **neutrale** [Interrogativadverb – auch: Frageadverb](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrogativadverb), mit dem man sich z.B. nach einem Gegenstand erkundigt: „Was hältst du in der Hand?“, im Gegensatz zu dem *persönlichen* Frageadverb „wer“, dessen Genitiv definitiv „wessen“ lautet.

Aber wie bildet man den Genitiv von „was“?

Auf [cafe-lingua.de](http://www.cafe-lingua.de/deutsche-grammatik/genitiv-wessen-fall.php) steht, er laute auch „wessen“. Ist es also korrekt, wenn ich frage „Wessen Dach stürzte ein?“ – „Das des Hauses.“ Für mich hört sich diese Kombination falsch an, da ich „wessen“ immer mit der Frage nach einem Menschen assoziiere. M.E. müsste die Antwort hier lauten: „Peters Dach stürzte ein.“

Laut [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/wessen) gilt „wessen“ hingegen nur als der Genitiv von „wer“.

Der [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/wessen) sagt:

> **wes­sen**: Genitiv von wer und was

Gehen wir also davon aus, dass „wessen“ auch für Neutra gilt. Nehmen wir folgenden Satz als Beispiel:

„Das Feuer ließ das Dach einstürzen.“

Wie bilde ich den Fragesatz nach der *Ursache* des Einsturzes mit „aufgrund ...“?

- „Aufgrund *wessen* stürzte das Dach ein?“

Mit dieser Frage wird suggeriert, dass die Ursache menschlicher Herkunft ist. Ich möchte aber lediglich unvoreingenommen nach dem Grund fragen!
Dieser Satz sollte nur ein Beispiel dafür sein, dass ich „wessen“ für menschlich halte. Ein getrenntes Betrachten von „wessen“ und „aufgrund wessen“ ergibt vermutlich keinen Sinn.

Deswegen verbleibt die Grundfrage: Wie bildet man den (neutralen) Genitiv von „was“?

Comment: Ähnlich: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/27586/was-ist-was-im-dativ Umschreibung mit _welcher_ funktioniert hier ebenfalls.

Comment: Die Vorstellung, dass Neutra benutzt werden, um Dinge zu bezeichnen, ist grundlegend falsch. Der Hammer ist ein Ding, die Zange ist ein Ding, das Mitglied ist ein Mensch, das Weib ist ein Mensch. "Wer oder was" sind Fragen des Nominativs. Nach einem Genitiv vom Nominativ zu fragen ist m.E. Quatsch. Frage: Wie wird aus dem Dach des Hauses bei Dir plötzlich das ganze Haus (Peters Haus)? Wenn Du nicht weißt, was den Einsturz verursacht hat, weißt Du auch nicht, ob es maskulin (der Sturm), neutral (das Feuer) oder feminin war (die Erschütterung). M.W. gibt es f. Menschen keine eigene Grammatik.

Comment: @userunknown es gibt für Menschen keine eigene Grammatik? Und wenn ich frage "Wer brachte mein Haus zum Einsturz?"? Diese Frage erkundigt sich doch ganz eindeutig nach einem Menschen. "Wessen Schuld ist es, dass das Haus brennt?" klingt für mich ebenso *menschlich*.  Wenn du aber sagst, dass "wessen" *nicht* als der Genitiv von "wer" zu verstehen ist, kann ich deine Meinung nachvollziehen

Comment: @Blauhirn: Schuld war nur der Bossa Nova...

Comment: @phil294: Menschen bringen in meinem Umfeld sehr selten Häuser zum Einsturz - ich würde eher auf das Erdbeben tippen. Genauso gut wie ein Mensch könnte es auch ein Hund gewesen sein. Oder der Orkan brachte das Haus zum Einsturz. Oder der Donnergott. Der Klimawandel in Gestalt einer Mure.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Wessen* ist der korrekte Genitiv zu *was* (und *wer*).

*Aufgrundwessen* existiert nicht (zumindest nicht im Duden; gehört habe ich es auch noch nie). Nach der Ursache kann man z.B. mit

*weshalb*, *warum*, *wieso* fragen.

Comment: *aus welchem Grund(e)?*  - *aufgrund des Feuers!* wäre auch eine Fragemöglichkeit, welche die Satzstruktur bewahrt. Dazu kommt dann noch *Weswegen*.

Answer (score 2):

Ich finde auch, dass “wessen Dach“ eine Person suggeriert und würde als Fragewort zu “welches Dach“ ausweichen, um die Beantwortung nicht einzuengen. Bei Präpositionen wie aufgrund gibt es andere Fragen, wie oben beschrieben. Eindeutiger wird es bei Verben/Adjektiven mit Genitivergäzung, z.B. er ist des xyz schuldig, wir klagen sie des xyz an. Dort geht als Frage nur wessen ist er schuldig? Wessen wird sie angeklagt? Und das gibt m.E. Klarheit darüber, dass wessen eben die Genitivform von was ist.

Comment: Ich möchte Sie bitten, sich an die üblichen Regeln zur Groß- und Kleinschreibung zu halten.

Comment: "welches Dach" - da würde mich jetzt der komplette Satz interessieren, der inhaltlich gleichbedeutend mit der Frage nach dem Grund des Dacheinsturzes ist.

Comment: "Das Dach der Sporthalle ist eingestürzt."/"Wessen Dach?"/"Das der Sporthalle."/"Nicht das des Schützenvereins?"/"Nein, der Sporthalle". Wessen suggeriert nur dem Suggestiblen eine Person. Zumal Personen normalerweise einen Kopf, vielleicht einen Hut aber kein Dach haben.

Comment: @userunknown, Du würdest wirklich „wessen Dach“ sagen? Dann sprichst Du gehobener als ich, ich würde mich wahrscheinlich mit „das Dach wovon“ behelfen, auch wenn das nicht elegant ist.