# Ist es möglich, "aus wessen Schuld" zu fragen?

Tags: grammar, usage, question, idiomaticity

Ich möchte wissen, ob folgende Sätze auf Deutsch richtig sind:

> Aus wessen Schuld tun Sie es dann?
>
> Ich weiß nicht, aus wessen Schuld.
>
> Aus wessen Schuld bist du nicht gekommen?

Es gäbe viele andere Beispiele, aber mich interessiert nur, ob es korrekt und möglich ist, die Frage "aus wessen Schuld" zu benutzen. Ich habe im Internet gegoogelt, aber gar nichts gefunden.

**Aktualisierung**: Ich habe bei Google Bücher recherchiert und habe die folgenden Ergebnisse gefunden:

> [Der stumme Advocat oder Josephs Antoni von Bandel Vertheidigung der heiligen ...](https://books.google.de/books?id=GANJAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA73&dq=aus+wessen+schuld&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiLqpilu-_KAhWJQJoKHXW7Af8Q6AEIRDAI#v=onepage&q=aus%20wessen%20schuld&f=false)
>
> [Christ-Catholischer SABBATH. Das ist: DOMINICALE, Oder Sonntags-Predigen Auf ...](https://books.google.de/books?id=2PZkAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA416&dq=aus+wessen+schuld&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiLqpilu-_KAhWJQJoKHXW7Af8Q6AEISTAJ#v=onepage&q=aus%20wessen%20schuld&f=false)
>
> [Ohne Schuld: Novelle](https://books.google.de/books?id=8NaUBwAAQBAJ&pg=PT31&dq=aus+wessen+schuld&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiR3-nBu-_KAhXDE5oKHbjxC_I4ChDoAQgmMAI#v=onepage&q=aus%20wessen%20schuld&f=false) (Aus wessen Sicht?)
>
> [Der Königl. Dänischen Missionarien aus Ost-Indien eingesandte ...](https://books.google.de/books?id=Dg1CAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA496&dq=aus+wessen+schuld&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiR3-nBu-_KAhXDE5oKHbjxC_I4ChDoAQg9MAY#v=onepage&q=aus%20wessen%20schuld&f=false)
>
> [Bemerkungen über die von Thiersch vorgeschlagene Organisation der gelehrten ...](https://books.google.de/books?id=479AAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA68&dq=aus+wessen+schuld&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiR3-nBu-_KAhXDE5oKHbjxC_I4ChDoAQhOMAk#v=onepage&q=aus%20wessen%20schuld&f=false)
>
> [Der Prediger](https://books.google.de/books?id=pmE_AAAAcAAJ&pg=PA27&dq=aus+wessen+schuld&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjr2_TNu-_KAhUoJ5oKHapQDCc4FBDoAQg_MAY#v=onepage&q=aus%20wessen%20schuld&f=false)
>
> [Archiv der Forst und- Jagd-Gesetzgebung der deutschen Bundesstaaten ...](https://books.google.de/books?id=8LcCAAAAYAAJ&pg=RA1-PA42&dq=aus+wessen+schuld&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjr2_TNu-_KAhUoJ5oKHapQDCc4FBDoAQg5MAU#v=onepage&q=aus%20wessen%20schuld&f=false)
>
> [Gesetze und Verfassungen im Justiz-Fache: 1821-1825 ...](https://books.google.de/books?id=3hMPAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA125&dq=aus+wessen+schuld&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjr2_TNu-_KAhUoJ5oKHapQDCc4FBDoAQhIMAg#v=onepage&q=aus%20wessen%20schuld&f=false)

Ich hoffe, dass diese nützlich sind. In einigen Fällen kann ich leider nicht richtig lesen, ob es *wessen* oder *weffen* ist.

Comment: related: [Was ist der Genitiv von “was”?](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/27952/was-ist-der-genitiv-von-was), [Was ist “was” im Dativ?](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/27586/was-ist-was-im-dativ)

Comment: Ich stimme dafür, diese Frage als off-topic zu schließen, weil die angenommene Ausgangskonstruktion »aus jemandes/etwas Schuld geschieht etwas« meines Erachtens nicht existiert.

Comment: @Jan Selbst wenn der entsprechende Antwort-/Aussagesatz ungrammatisch ist, macht das die Frage nach der Frage nicht off-topic.

Comment: Wenn Google gar keine Ergebnisse bringt, ist doch klar, dass die Wendung gar nichts existiert! @Crissov: Man kann StackExchange auch zumüllen mit Fragen wie "Warum existiert dies und das nicht in einer Sprache?"

Comment: Die bei [DWDS](http://dwds.de/?view=1&qu=%22aus+*+Schuld%22) abgefragten Korpora bringen u.a. Beispiele mit _aus eigener / der / aller / ihrer / unserer / seiner / deiner / individueller / moralischer / verdrängter / historischer / schlimmer / persönlicher Schuld_, aber in vielen Fällen wird dort kein Grund, sondern ein Ursprung (_aus … Schuld heraus_ o.ä.) angegeben.

Comment: FYI: weffen gibt es nicht, aber das S sah dem F mal verdammt ähnlich.

Comment: Ich habe das Danke und die Entschuldigung aus deiner Frage gelöscht. Es ist hier nicht üblich, die Frage unnötig damit aufzublähen. Wir konzentrieren uns in dem Text auf das Wesentliche. Danke sagst du, indem du eine jede gute und hilfreiche Antwort upvotest und die für dich Beste "akzeptierst".

Comment: Man verwendet ganz einfach "warum". Warum tun sie es dann?  Warum bist du nicht gekommen? "Aus wessen Schuld" ist Unsinn.

Comment: Das ist interessant, aber ein wenig habe ich das Gefühl, dass Dein Zusatz die Frage verändert hat, nachdem sie beantwortet wurde. Er macht nämlich klar, dass es nicht nur um aktuelles Deutsch geht.

Answer (score 4):

Korrekt ist "Wessen Schuld ist es?" und "Es ist jemandes Schuld".

Beim ersten Satz bin ich mir nicht sicher, was du sagen möchtest. Selbst grammatikalisch richtig ergibt der Satz nicht viel Sinn. Ein Wort, das hier sinnvoll eingesetzt werden kann, ist *Grund*.

> Aus welchem Grund[=Warum] tun sie es dann?

Eine Formulierung mit *Schuld* wäre

> Wessen Schuld ist es, dass sie es tun?

wobei mir hier kein sinnvoller Kontext einfällt, wo man dies so verwenden würde.

Auch der zweite Satz ist etwas merkwürdig. Sinn ergibt:

> Ich weiß nicht, wessen Schuld es ist.

Falls der zweite Satz jedoch die Antwort zur Frage im ersten Beispiel sein soll, wäre es:

> Ich weiß nicht, aus welchem Grund[=warum].

Beachte, dass das zwei ganz verschiedene Ideen sind und kein Zusammenhang vorliegt. Grund/Ursache versus Schuld/Verantwortung.

Der dritte Satz kann sowohl mit *Schuld* als auch *Grund* formuliert werden, wobei erneut der Kern der Frage eine unterschiedliche Implikation aufweist.

> Aus welchem Grund[=Warum] bist du nich gekommen? -> Was ist die Ursache?
>   Wessen Schuld ist es, dass du nicht gekommen bist? -> Wer ist verantwortlich?

Die Kollokation *aus* + *Schuld* gibt es so, wie du's versucht hast, nicht. Was man aber sagen kann, ist

> Der Unfall wurde aus eigener Schuld verursacht.

Dieser Satz besagt, dass man selber verantwortlich ist für den Unfall.

Answer (score 3):

Die Sätze ergeben für mich keinen Sinn und werden so niemals verwendet.
Du kannst folgendes sagen:

> Warum / Weswegen / Aus welchem Grund tun Sie es dann?
>   Ich weiß nicht, weshalb / warum / aus welchem Grund.
>   Warum / Weswegen / Aus welchem Grund bist du nicht gekommen?

Comment: vermuten wir, dass ich als Anwalt die Verteidigung gegen jemanden/von jemandem nehme, um den Unschuldige und Schuldige zu erkennen, meiner Meinung nach, aber ich bin nicht sicher, haben die Sätze, die ich geschrieben habe, einen Sinn vielleicht einen  situationsbezogenen Sinn.. was denkst du hierzu?

Comment: In der Originalformulierung macht es keinen Sinn und ist tendenziell Grammatikalisch falsch.
Eine Formulierung wie "Wessen Schuld war es, dass du zu spät warst?" wäre jedoch gut denkbar und gebräuchlich. (Wobei diese Formulierung für einen Anwalt mit großer Wahrscheinlichkeit etwas zu umgangssprachlich wäre.)

Comment: -1 weil in der Antwort überhaupt nicht auf Schuld die die korrekte Verwendung des Wortes eingegangen wird.

Comment: Dann hab ich ihn missverstanden.

Comment: @BenSower, Danke! ;)

Answer (score 3):

Die Konstruktion ist schon als Aussagesatz nicht richtig. Man sagt nicht "Aus meiner Schuld bin ich zu spät gekommen", sondern z.B. "Ich bin selbst Schuld, daß ich zu spät gekommen bin."

Comment: Und die passende Frage zu dem Aussagesatz würde dann wie lauten? Und gibt es eine andere Alternative, die ähnlich zur Konstruktion "aus wessen Schuld" ist?

Comment: "Wegen wem/was, bist du zu spät gekommen?" wäre eine umgangssprachliche Formulierung, für eine seriösere Formulierung würde ich etwas weiter ausholen und "Was war der Grund/die Ursache dafür, dass sie sich verspätet haben?". Diese Formulierung ist -wenn nicht explizit biased betont- in sich neutral und trägt keine Wertigkeit gegenüber der Schuldfrage.

Comment: Richtig ist "Ich bin schuld." siehe: http://www.spiegel.de/kultur/zwiebelfisch/zwiebelfisch-abc-schuld-schuld-a-437082.html

Comment: _Aus **eigener** Schuld_ funktioniert hingegen, auch wenn _selbstverschuldet_ stilistisch schöner sein mag.

Comment: @Kilian Foth, ja, ich weiss, dass es "selbst Schuld" heißt oder "meinetwegen" auch, und ich kenne die Alternative "ich bin Schuld,..." oder andere, aber von meinen Sätze ist keiner ein "Aussagesatz". Trotzdem Vielen Dank! ;)

Answer (score 1):

> Aus wessen Schuld

ist nicht richtig.
In manchen Fällen kann

> durch wessen Schuld

verwendet werden.

> Z.B. Durch wessen Schuld bist du nicht gekommen.

Das klingt aber meisten seltsam. Ich würde eher eine andere Formulierung wie z.B. die aus der Antwort von @Killian Foth verwenden.

Comment: ich kann mir ehrlichgesagt keinen korrekten deutschen satz vorstellen, indem "durch wessen Schuld" verwendet werden kann ;)

Comment: Ich habe ein Beispiel hinzugefügt.

Comment: Es gibt schon Möglichkeiten, einen korrekten Satz zu konstruieren mit der Phrase "aus wessen Schuld". Etwa könnte ein Pfarrer sagen "Es gibt immer Hoffnung. Aus wessen Schuld gibt es keinen Ausweg?"

Comment: @Bort ja du hast recht, aber mit "durch" klingt es in meinen ohren ziemlich falsch...

Answer (score 1):

Ist das möglich? Ja sicher. Du hast selbst bewiesen, dass das machbar ist.

Stilistisch steckt da aber enormes Verbesserungspotential drinnen. Grammatisch sind deine Sätze korrekt, wenn man das Problem der Syntax mal außer Acht lässt.

Syntaktisch sind diese Sätze nämlich nur sinnvoll, wenn man das Wort »Schuld« mit einer neuen Bedeutung belegt, die es üblicherweise nicht hat. Das Problem ist die Präposition "aus" zusammen mit "tun" erwartet man da eine Ursache oder ein Motiv für die Handlung:

> Die Frau tötete ihren Mann **aus Verzweiflung**.
>   Leo steckte **aus reiner Neugier** seinen Kopf aus dem Fenster.
>   **Aus reiner Langeweile** baute Ludwig Neuhofer den Eifelturm aus Streichhölzern nach.

Schuld ist aber nicht das, was jemanden veranlasst eine Handlung auszuüben. Das Motiv einer Handlung existiert immer schon vor der Handlung. Die Schuld entsteht - wenn überhaupt - erst während man handelt. Sie ist ein ungewolltes, aber häufig in Kauf genommenes, Ergebnis einer Handlung.

Answer (score 1):

Im katholischen Gottesdienst gibt es einen Ritus, in dem die Gemeinde ihre Sünden bekennt. Dabei murmeln alle formelhaft:

> Ich habe gesündigt, in Gedanken, Worten und Werken, durch meine
>   Schuld, durch meine Schuld, durch meine große Schuld.

Im Alltag ist mir eine solche Formulierung aber nicht geläufig. Ich vermute es war früher eine gängige Formulierung, die wg. ihrer Formelhaftigkeit dem Sprachwandel getrotzt hat, so wie auch heute niemand 'gebenedeit' sagt, aber das entsprechende Gebet weiterhin so lautet.

Comment: Das ist eine direkte Übersetzung von "mea culpa, mea culpa, mea maxima culpa", also Ablativ (hier in der Funktion des Ablativus Instrumentalis).