# unbelebte Dativobjekte: Fragesatz in korrektem Deutsch gesucht

Tags: dative, question

**Beispielsatz mit dem belebten Dativobjekt "der Fussgängerin":**

> Er konnte mit seinem Fahrrad der Fußgängerin gerade noch ausweichen.

zugehörige Frage:

> Wem konnte er mit seinem Fahrrad gerade noch ausweichen?
>   → Wem- Frage

**Beispielsatz mit dem unbelebten Dativobjekt "dem Schlag":**

> Er muss dem Schlag schnell ausweichen.

Ich suche die **zugehörige Frage** zu diesem Satz.
Ich denke „Was muss er schnell ausweichen?“, ist falsch.
Ich denke „Wem muss er schnell ausweichen?“, ist auch falsch, da der Schlag keine Person ist.

Gibt es zu diesem Satz eine passende Frage?

Comment: Warum gehst du davon aus, dass eine Wem-Frage nur für Menschen gilt?

Comment: @Iris Ich weiß zwar nicht, warum Wogehu davon ausgeht, aber bei einer "Wer"-Frage (Nominativ) wäre es so: "*Wer liegt im Bett?*" oder: "*Was liegt im Bett?*"

Comment: @Martin Rosenau, stimmt, es gibt die "Wer oder was?" und die "Wen oder was?"-Fragen, aber nur "Wessen" und "Wem"-Fragen.

Comment: Ich habe nochmals etwas recherchiert. 
Quelle: Duden Band 4: Die Grammatik; Auflage 8.  
Zitat Seite 307: Bei der Frage nach unbelebten Dativobjekten besteht eine Lücke, man muss sich mit Umschreibungen behelfen: 
Beispiel: "Wem gleicht dieses Haus?" (Kann nur als Dativ von "wer" aufgefasst werden, also als Frage nach einer Person. Möglicher Ausweg: "Womit ist dieses Haus vergleichbar?"                     - Nun frage ich mich, mit was für einer Umschreibung ich die Frage zu obigem Satz "Er muss dem Schlag schnell ausweichen" bilden könnte?

Answer (score 6):

Die richtige Frage lautet:

> **Wem** muss ich schnell ausweichen?

Falsch war lediglich das Satzzeichen am Ende der Frage (das darf kein Punkt sein, sondern muss ein Fragezeichen sein.)

Nach einem Satzbestandteil, der im Dativ steht, fragt man immer mit »wem«:

> Hans schuldet Otto Geld.
>   **Wem** schuldet Hans Geld?
>
> Hans schuldet der Bank Geld.
>   **Wem** schuldet Hans Geld?

An diesem Beispiel kannst Du sehen:

Wenn du die Frage stellst, weißt du vorher die Antwort nicht. Du weißt zum Zeitpunkt der Frage also nicht, ob Hans sein Geld einer Person oder einer Institution schuldet.

> Wem musstest du ausweichen?
>   Ich musste dem Bus ausweichen.

Dasselbe gilt bei Fragen nach dem Genitiv:

> Wessen Schuld ist das?
>   Das ist Lisas Schuld.
>   Das ist die Schuld der Firma.

Einen Unterschied zwischen Personen und Nicht-Personen gibt nur im Nominativ und im Akkusativ. Daher fragt man, wenn man nicht weiß, ob die Antwort eine Person oder etwas anders sein wird, im Fall des Nominativs nicht mit »wer« und auch nicht mit »was«, sondern mit »wer oder was«:

> Wer oder was ist Schuld daran?
>   Hans ist Schuld daran.
>   Die Versicherung ist Schuld daran.

Detto im Akkusativ:

> Wen oder was siehst du?
>   Ich sehe Maria.
>   Ich sehen dein Auto.

---

Schwieriger wird es, wenn eine Präposition hinzukommt:

> Eva liegt **auf** dem Sofa.

Hier kann man keine Frage stellen, die direkt mit einem Fragewort beginnt. (»Wem liegt Eva auf?« ist falsch) Man muss die Frage schon mit der Präposition beginnen:

> Auf **wem** liegt Eva?

Das wäre zwar eine korrekte Frage, impliziert aber in der Tat, dass Eva auf einer Person liegt. Die Alternative worauf:

> **Worauf** liegt Eva?

Man ersetzt also »auf wem« durch »worauf«. Das geht in diesem Fall deswegen, weil »auf dem Sofa« ein versteckter Lokativ ist, und »worauf« das Fragewort für den Lokativ ist. Der Lokativ ist im Deutschen aber nicht als eigenständiger Fall realisiert, sondern wird mit

> <*Lokalpräposition*> +  <*Dativobjekt*>

gebildet.

Das heißt: es gibt in diesem Beispiel zwar einen Dativ, aber der ist nur eine Krücke um den (in reiner Form gar nicht existierenden) Lokativ zu bilden.

Andere Sprachen haben einen echten Lokativ. Da kommt man in so einem Fall gar nicht in die Verlegenheit eine Dativ-Frage zu stellen, weil der dann in der Antwort gar nicht vorkommt.

Ähnliches gilt gilt auch für andere grammatische Fälle, die im Deutschen realisiert werden, indem man eine Präposition an einen Dativ oder Akkusativ (seltener auch an den Genitiv) bildet.

Comment: Hier im Forum wurde fast dieselbe Frage bereits einmal gestellt: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/27586/was-ist-was-im-dativ. Die Antwort dort - wenn ich sie richtig verstehe: Immer nur "wem?" nehmen, geht auch nicht...

Comment: _**Wovor** musstest du ausweichen?_ geht auch, impliziert aber (erzwingt jedoch nicht) eine Antwort mit _vor_.

Comment: @Crissov: 1. Ich denke doch, dass »*wovor*« ausdrücklich eine Antwort mit der Präposition »*vor*« erzwingt. 2. Ich glaube nicht, dass man *vor* etwas ausweicht. Man läuft *vor* etwas davon oder hat *vor* etwas Angst (Wovor läufst du davon? Wovor hast du Angst?). Aber man weicht ganz einfach aus. Man weicht nicht *vor* etwas aus, daher kann man auch nicht fragen, *wovor* man ausweicht, sondern man fragt eben danach *wem* man ausweicht.