# How to ask for a dative object?

Tags: grammatical-case, dative, question

I know that *wem* is the dative question, in contrast with the accusative questions *wen* and *was*.

But there is the verb *folgen*, which always takes the dative, e.g., in “Ich folge dem Auto”.
How do I ask in German:

> What are you following?

1. > Was folgst du?

   Here I ask *was* even though I am in dative.
2. > Wonach folgst du?

   Here I use the *wo* words but I'm not sure if that is right because the infinitive is not *folgen nach.*

Is either of my attempts correct? If not, what is?

Comment: *Here i ask "was" even though i am in Dative.* I have to ask: Why?

Comment: What lets you believe that "was" is *not* dative?

Comment: Very much related: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/27586/was-ist-was-im-dativ

Comment: This is actually more subtle than it seems, related question in German: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/27586/was-ist-was-im-dativ

Comment: Maybe an english explanation?

Comment: "What do you follow?" is not a question I would ask in English in the first place. Sounds like a question about my twitter habits, but it feels weird to me.

Comment: I really don't find these wer-wen-wem-wes-questions very helpful, since they contain a circular argument for which case to chose. You have to know the answer beforehand to ask the correct question.

Comment: Hi @Tomas, I do not find your question particularly clear, maybe you can work on that. Keep in mind that the idea of this site is that questions are not only useful for the person asking them but also for future visitors. With those in mind, please put some care into formulating the question. The question asked in German has been mentioned for reference, not to discourage answers. It is site policy that having the same question in both English and German is useful. Otherwise I would have voted to close your question as a duplicate.

Comment: Someone has already answered well, so i guess it is clear what i asked... As you wish if u wanna delete it, delete. But maybe consider answering instead

Comment: "As you wish if u wanna delete it, delete." This is the point where I realise that I have put more effort into this question than you have.

Comment: @tofro Laut Wiktionary hat *was* keine Dativform. https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/was

Answer (score 4):

The question is:

> **Wem** folgst du?

As you said: *folgen* needs its object in dative case, so when you have to ask for this object, you use *wem* to ask.

Other examples:

> Die Autobahn gehört dem Staat.
> **Wem** gehört die Autobahn?
>
> Die Ziffer 0 ähnelt dem Buchstaben O.
> **Wem** ähnelt die Ziffer 0?
>
> Ernst ist der Biertrinkerpartei beigetreten.
> **Wem** ist Ernst beigetreten?
>
> Der Suppe fehlt Salz.
> **Wem** fehlt Salz?

Comment: I really don't find these wer-wen-wem-wes-questions very helpful, since they contain a circular argument for which case to chose. You have to know the answer beforehand to ask the correct question

Comment: I know the answer= Ich folge dem Auto

Comment: "Zu *was* bist du eingeladen?" - "Zum Geburtstag" - You would probably not ask "zu *wem* bist du eingeladen?", because that would yield the answer "zu Hubert". Agreed this could be considered colloquial, even dialect.

Comment: @Beta, the OP asked what the question is, so your comment does not really fit the situation.

Comment: @tofro isn't it supposed to be "wozu"? instead of "zu was"

Comment: But "wem" isn't only for people? I mean the car is Something and not someone.

So i always ask "wem" in Dative, even if im reffering to a thing?

Comment: @tofro: Das ist eine eigene Frage wert. Meine Antwort würde den Rahmen mehrerer Kommentare sprengen.

Comment: @Tomas: No. I intentionally used examples in my answer, that show you that your assumption is wrong. Neither a highway, nor soup nor a letter nor a party are persons. But you ask for them with *wem* if the are used in dative case.

Comment: @ Hubert Schölnast: In my opinion any '_Zusammenschluss_' or community of people and even a state or an enterprise can be addressed as a quasi person. The meaning of the second example would rather be translated by '_Welchem anderen Schriftzeichen / Welchem Buchstaben ähnelt die Ziffer '0' / das Zeichen für die Zahl '0'?'_, the third question by '_Welcher Partei ist Ernst beigetreten?_' And a head chef in a restaurant after inviting his apprentice or trainee to taste two soups would not ask '_Na, wem fehlt jetzt das Salz?'_. [weiter ...]

Comment: [... weiter]  He would rather say: '_Na, was sagst du, wo fehlt jetzt das Salz?_' There is a big difference between 'grammatically possible' and real life language. As I wrote in my German answer the pronouns '_wer/wen/wem?_' will be interpreted as referring to humans whenever possible. A statement like '_wem is the dative of was_' would be wrong.

Comment: @Hubert Schölnast: Ich schreib's noch mal auf Deutsch, damit's auch wirklich verstanden wird: 'Wem fehlt Salz?' bezogen auf eine Suppe wäre für mich falsch, und für die Duden-Grammatik auch. Ich könnte theoretisch die Nachbarin meinen, aber ein solcher Satz macht kommunikativ keinen Sinn, eher: '_Was wollte die Nachbarin? - Ihr fehlte Salz / Sie hat nach etwas Salz gefragt._' Ob selbstfahrende Autos als Personen adressiert werden können, muss sich erst noch herausstellen. Eine Frage wie die des OP würde üblicherweise lauten '_Welchem Auto soll ich folgen?_'

Comment: @RalfJoerres: Wenn ich frage »Welchen Auto soll ich folgen«, dann ist ja schon bekannt, dass ich einem Auto folgen soll. Aber genau das sollte ja mit der Frage erfragt werden. »Welchem Auto ...« fragt nach einem konkretem Exemplar innerhalb einer Kategorie. Das funktioniert aber nicht, wenn man eigentlich (auch) nach der der Kategorie fragt. Und ja, natürlich: Die Antwort auf »Wem fehlt Salz« kann natürlich auch »Ilse« sein, weil jedes Dativobjekt als Antwort geeignet ist. Die Antwort kann aber eben auch »der Suppe« oder auch »der Autobahnmeisterei« sein. Je nach Kontext.

Comment: @Hubert Schölnast: Ich kann mir keine Straße vorstellen, auf der beliebige Gegenstände unterwegs sind, so dass man erst noch die Kategorie eingrenzen muss, auf die eine folgen-Frage zielt. Ein Kfz ist am wahrscheinlichsten, es könnte auch ein Fahrrad sein, aber so ist der Kontext im OP nicht skizziert. Schon richtig, man könnte fragen, 'wem  folgst du (da)?'. Keine Ahnung, wie Du das verstehst, ich würde es immer in letzter Konsequenz als Frage nach einem Verkehrsteilnehmer verstehen. Auch wenn ich etwa sagen würde, ich folge der roten Jacke, wäre das eine sozusagen metaphorische [weiter ...]

Comment: [... weiter] bzw. metonymische Bezeichnung für 'ich folge der Person in der roten Jacke'. Bei der Suppe liegt der Fall für mich völlig klar: Kein Koch im deutschsprachigen Raum würde bei zwei Töpfen Suppe, von denen einer nachgesalzen werden muss, eine Frage dazu als 'wem fehlt das Salz?' formulieren, das klingt mehr als befremdlich und das wirst Du nicht im Ernst aufrechterhalten wollen. Wie stehst Du zu dem bereits zitierten Duden-Befund, dass 'wem' sich nur auf Personen beziehen kann und dass in solchen Fällen umschrieben werden muss?

Answer (score 1):

[Für eine schnelle Antwort siehe die Beispielssätze 11 und 12.]

Ich entscheide vorerst, ohne eine Grammatik zu befragen. Für mich kann ein allein stehendes '*was*?' nur Nominativ oder Akkusativ sein, nicht jedoch Dativ:

> 1 *was tut das schwache Drehbuch keinen Abbruch? - Antwort: der Spannung

Da andererseits kein kommunikativer Anlass vorstellbar ist, um eine derartige Frage zu stellen, besteht in diesem Satz für ein Dativ-*was* auch kein echter Bedarf.

Auch das frei stehende indefinite Pronomen '*etwas*' ist als Dativobjekt - anders als hinter einer Dativ-fordernden Präposition - zumindest fragwürdig [siehe Anmerkung 1]:

> 2 */?er versuchte, etwas auszuweichen, das auf der Fahrbahn lag

Umgekehrt wird '*wer*?' '*wen*?' '*wem*?' in allen Fällen, bei denen man diese Fragepronomen auf Personen bezogen verstehen **kann**, als Frage nach einer Person interpretiert:

> 3 wem kannst du nicht folgen?

würde eher interpretiert als

> 4 welcher Person kannst du in ihrem argumentativen Gedankengang nicht folgen?

als

> 5 welcher Beweisführung kannst du nicht folgen?

Es wäre die Frage, ob Gesellschaften (Personengemeinschaften), Körperschaften, Organisationen nicht auch als personen-analog - also als nicht sachgegenständlich - verstanden werden und mit '*wer / wen / wem*' adressiert werden können.

Andererseits hat das System der Frage- und indefiniten Pronomen mit Bezug auf Sachen für mich Leerstellen [siehe Anmerkung 1 und 2]. Wiederum kann '*wessen*?' jedoch auch bezogen auf genitivische Sachobjekte eingesetzt werden:

> 6 wessen wurde er beschuldigt?

Derartige Sachobjekte stehen jedoch (oft?) mit personalen Urhebern in einer Kontiguitätsbeziehung.

Ob ein

> 7 wessen erinnerst du dich noch?

auf eine Person oder auf eine Sache bezogen verstanden würde, könnte kontextabhängig sein; der Satz ist stilistisch 'abgehoben' und klingt heutzutage gekünstelt, man würde eher fragen

> 8 woran / an was erinnerst du dich noch?

oder

> 9 an wen erinnerst du dich noch?

Möglicherweise korrekt, aber stilistisch übers Knie gebrochen klingen für mich Fragen nach Sach-Dativen mit '*welcher Sache*' / '*welchem Ding*'. Solche Fragen denken sich Grammatiker aus, sie kommen in natürlicher Sprache nicht vor. Die Bedeutung '*etwas*' im Dativ kann jedoch (oft?) mit '*einer Sache*' wiedergegeben werden:

> 10 er versuchte, einer Sache (oder: einem Gegenstand) auf der Fahrbahn auszuweichen

Bei den angefragten Sätzen sehe ich nur folgende Möglichkeiten:

> 11 Welchem Fahrzeug folgst du?

oder, da ein nicht frei stehendes '*was*' hinter einer Präposition auch im Dativ stehen kann, man weicht auf ein anderes Verb aus, an das ein präpositionales Objekt anschließt:

> 12 Hinter was bist du her?

---

[Anmerkung 1] In der Duden-Grammatik 2006 heißt es auf S. 323 unter Rz 419: "Das Indefinitum (...) *etwas* (...) erhält keine Flexionsendungen (...) Es tritt als Artikelwort und Pronomen im Nominativ und Akkusativ so wie nach Präpositionen (auch solchen mit dem Dativ) auf (...)"

[Anmerkung 2] Die Duden-Grammatik von 2006 schreibt auf S. 314 unter Rz 406: "Bei der Frage nach unbelebten Dativobjekten besteht eine Lücke, man muss sich mit Umschreibungen behelfen:
*Wem gleicht dieses Haus? (Kann nur als Dativ von *wer* aufgefasst werden, also als Frage nach einer Person. Möglicher Ausweg: Womit ist dieses Haus vergleichbar?)"

Answer (score 0):

For learners of German the grammar case questions *wer, wessen, wen,* and *wem* may have not the value they have for native speakers.

All of these questions have in common that in most cases **you already have to know** which grammatical case follows in order to ask the proper question.

So your confusion is no suprise. It comes from the widespread (mis-)believe that teaching people to ask those qestion will resolve the case dilemma. Well it does if you heard the questions many times before, and if by this you almost know the appropriate cases:

> ***Wen*** verfolge ich? not <del>*Wem verfolge ich?*</del>
>   ***Wem*** folge ich? not <del>*Wen folge ich?*</del>